# C++11 way of finding shortest prefix of a vector with sum > threshold

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

If I have a `vector<int>` , what is a concise C++11 way to find the shortest
prefix with sum > threshold ?

Comment: Can you provide an example? I'm not sure I understand what you mean

Comment: Suppose v = <4, 8, 11, 7> and threshold is 10, then the shortest prefix is <4, 8> being the first segment whose accumulated sum > 10. If threshold is 50, then the prefix is empty. Results could be returned as iterators.

Comment: `std::accumulate` and search in a sorted list?

Comment: @BenVoigt: Works, but you add up values which you don't need. E.g. with threshold=10, 4+8 is needed but 4+8+11 isn't.

Comment: Feels like a code golf question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
template <class Iter>
Iter find_prefix(Iter first, Iter last,
    typename std::iterator_traits<Iter>::value_type threshold) {
    Iter tmp = first;
    while (tmp != last) {
        if (threshold <= *tmp)
            return ++tmp;
        else
            threshold -= *tmp++;
    }
return first;
}
```

This works for any arithmetic type and for any sequence of values represented by a forward iterator, not just a sequence managed by a `vector`.

Answer (score 1):

```
int sum=0,threshold=10;
vector<int> vi = {4, 8, 11, 7};
auto sprefix = std::find_if(begin(v), end(v), [&](int elem){sum+=elem;return (sum>threshold);});
```

Comment: I think you should return elements while `sum < threshold`, since `sum > threshold` marks the end of the subsequence.

Comment: No, this is roughly correct. `find_if` returns the first element for which the condition is true, so that condition must be the end of the sequence. Of course, per C++ conventions, you should return the _next_ iterator. `*sprefix` should be 11, not 8.

Comment: Yes the sequence is `[ v.begin(), sprefix )`

Comment: This is not correct: if the threshold was 2 then you should return [begin(v), begin(v) + 1) not [begin(v), begin(v)), which is empty.

Answer (score 0):

```
int size = vect.size(), length = -1, sum = 0;
while(++length < size)
    if( (sum += vect[length]) > threshold) break;
if(length == size) length = -1; // the whole sum is below the threshold!
```

`length` is the index of the last prefix element, which contains `length+1` numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I found an excuse to use a `mutable` lamba!

```
int n = 0;
auto iter = std::find_if(v.begin(), v.end(), [=](int x) mutable
    {
        n += x;
        return n > threshold;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This problem has O(n) time complexity, so an efficient way to do so would be:

```
int rangeIndex(vector<int>arr, int threshold)
{
    int i,sum = 0;

    for(i=0;i<arr.size();i++)
    {
        sum+=arr[i];

        if(sum>threshold)
        {
           return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

This function returns the index which marks the end of the shortest prefix which has sum greater than the threshold. If no such prefix is found to exist, the function returns -1.